# White patch in iPad mini in Arabic page

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

There are white patches when the page loads in iPad mini. It loads completely on  orientation change.

[image]

When checked in chrome developer's simulator, the page is completely blank, and appears on mouse scroll or page resize.

When the `direction: rtl;` for `body` is removed, it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove RTL from **body** and add it to **.container_12**